# elasticsearch.yml ses email config

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ses

Took the config from elastic search documentation, and added it to elastic cloud yml.

```
xpack.notification.email.account:
  ses_account:
    smtp:
      auth: true
      starttls.enable: true
      starttls.required: true
      host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
      port: 587
      user: <username>
      password: <password>
```

giving me the below error:

```
'xpack.notification.email.account.ses_account.profile': is not allowed
```

Comment: which version ?

Comment: v6.2.4 in Elastic Cloud

Comment: It may be disabled, you should contact elastic cloud support.